# PHP DOM array - cut the first element - better way to do it

Tags: php, arrays, dom

I'm really stucked and don't know how to implement an idea better. So, we have an XML file:

[image]

I've got an array by function dom_to_array()

```
function dom2array($node) {$result = array(); 
if($node->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) { 
    $result = $node->nodeValue; 
} 
else { 
    if($node->hasAttributes()) { 
        $attributes = $node->attributes; 
        if(!is_null($attributes))  
            foreach ($attributes as $index=>$attr)  
                $result[$attr->name] = $attr->value; 
    } 
    if($node->hasChildNodes()){ 
        $children = $node->childNodes; 
        for($i=0;$i<$children->length;$i++) { 
            $child = $children->item($i); 
            if($child->nodeName != '#text') 
            if(!isset($result[$child->nodeName])) 
                $result[$child->nodeName] = $this->dom2array($child); 
            else { 
                $aux = $result[$child->nodeName]; 
                $result[$child->nodeName] = array( $aux ); 
                $result[$child->nodeName][] = $this->dom2array($child); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 
return $result;
```

}

I've got an array with *first* XML element - STRUCTURE.

Array
--STRUCTURE
     ----PAGE
     ----PAGE
       -- -- --PAGE
     ----PAGE

So the main question is how make array looks like this:

Array
     ----PAGE
     ----PAGE
       -- -- --PAGE
     ----PAGE

How to do it better friends - i don't need to include "structure" into array, is it possible to create by DOM functions ?!

Comment: Maybe you could post the xml as plain text in your question? Typing it from the image in order to play around with your code is a bit tedious. ;)

Comment: Please - look at http://www.nulllab.net/usr/xml/tree.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you just want to exclude the `structure` level from the created PHP array?

I guess, you do something like this right now:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$array = dom2array($dom);
```

The resulting array includes the `structure` key.

What you can do is start from the structure element like so:

```
...
$array = dom2array($dom->getElementsByTagName('structure')->item(0));
```

Or you leave it as is and do it this way using the array key:

```
$array = dom2array($dom);
$array = $array['structure']; // set $array to the subelements of "structure"
```

Comment: Max, you the MAN ! Thank you very much !!

PS Come to Russia, drink vodka !

Comment: @Vovan Thank you, glad I could help :-) btw. Vodka is really my favorite drink ;)